# Regular Expression to match 6-15 alphanumeric characters plus symbols above 1-8 keys on keyboard

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a regular expression that allows between 6 - 15 characters and can be a-zA-Z0-9 and the symbols above the numbers <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> on a keyboard.

Here's what I have but it doesn't work.

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_][\!\@\#\$\%\^&\*]{5,16}+$/'
```

Comment: 6-16 characters would be {6,16}, not {5,16}.  Likely don't want the '+' either...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you have two different sets within brackets.  Basically the expression says "1 of a-zA-Z0-9-_" followed by 5-16 of special characters.  Combine them into the same set of brackets and you're all good.

Something like the following:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\!\@\#\$\%\^&\*]{5,16}$/'
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for explaining not only the correct answer but what was wrong with my answer.

Comment: No prob.  Regular expressions can get pretty out of hand, so I always try to read them and translate into plain language to check my work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[\w-!@#$%^&*]{6,15}$
```

As `\w` means `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Comment: You need to escape most of the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*]{5,16}$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[\w\!\@\#\$\%\^&\]{6,15}$/
```

That is what it would be in Perl.